How can the Finite Element Method be used to solve a Multi-equation System?
Every explanation I've seen of FEM show it solving an equation of the form $\mathcal{L}\phi=f$, with $\mathcal{L}$ being a differential operator, and every solution (whether it be Ritz or Galerkin) depends on there being only one equation and some boundary conditions.
So my question is: How would one use FEM to solve something like Maxwell's Equations for an arbitrary system?

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

This is somewhat hard to answer nicely since you refer to the 'explanations of FEM you have seen' but there are many introductory explanations of FEM that depend on the field you come from (typically mathematics or engineering). If you write out the approach you know it will be relatively straightforward to show how it generalizes to more than one equation.

I've read the first 4 chapters of Jin, Jian-Ming, – The finite element method in electromagnetics Third edition, which explains FEM with both Galerkin and Ritz methods for each of it's examples in how to find the FEM equations. Though he does not go into much detail on what the limits on $\mathcal{L}$ are.

@Korf to be more specific Jin, Jian-Ming prefers to use the method of minimizing the functional $F(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\left<\mathcal{L}\phi,\phi\right> - \frac{1}{2}\left<\phi,f\right> - \frac{1}{2}\left<f,\phi\right>$ where $\left<\phi,\psi\right> = \int_\Omega \phi\psi^* d\Omega$

Setting up the finite element problem for a system is relatively simple once you understand the general theory of FEM. Suppose we have the following system:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}_{11}u + \mathcal{L}_{12}v &= 0\in\mathcal{U} \\
\mathcal{L}_{21}u + \mathcal{L}_{22}v &= 0\in\mathcal{V}
\end{aligned}
$$
with corresponding function spaces, finite-dimensional subspaces, and bases $\mathcal{U}$, $\mathcal{U}^h$, and $\{\varphi_i\}_{i=1}^m$ and $\mathcal{V}$, $\mathcal{V}^h$, and $\{\psi_i\}_{i=1}^n$ for $u$ and $v$, respectively. The function space notation in the original equation just means that the first and second equation take values in the different spaces. For example, if $u$ and $v$ wre density and momentum, then the two equations might be the contiuity and conservation of momentum equations and we should keep track of which space these equations correspond to. Also denote the inner products on $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ as $(\!(\cdot,\cdot)\!)_{\mathcal{U}}$ and $(\!(\cdot,\cdot)\!)_{\mathcal{V}}$. What we wish to do now is create a function space, an inner product, and a finite-dimensional basis that allow us to rewrite this as a single equation. We do this via the direct product of the two function spaces. This essentially creates a new space of ordered pairs of elements of the original spaces, i.e., $w = (u,v)$.
We define $\mathcal{W} = \mathcal{U}\times\mathcal{V}$, $\mathcal{W}^h = \mathcal{U}^h\times\mathcal{V}^h$, and inner product $\langle w_1,w_2\rangle = (\!(u_1,u_2)\!)_{\mathcal{U}}+(\!(v_1,v_2)\!)_{\mathcal{V}},$ where $w_i = (u_i,v_i)\in\mathcal{W}$. So far this is all abstract, but the power of this formulation becomes clear when we wish to construct a basis of $\mathcal{W}^h$. Notice that, since each element of $\mathcal{W}^h$ is just an ordered pair of elements of $\mathcal{U}^h$ and $\mathcal{V}^h$, the set $\{(\varphi_1,0),\dots,(\varphi_m,0),(0,\psi_1),\dots,(0,\psi_n)\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{W}^h$. There are exactly $m+n$ elements of this basis, which we denote $\{\eta_i\}_{i=1}^{m+n}$. Algebraically, the order of the basis does not matter, but for implementation, it will matter a great deal as we shall soon see. For the time being let us assume we are using this natural ordering. We can also rewrite our original system of equations as a single vector equation:
$$
\mathcal{L}w = (\mathcal{L}_{11}u + \mathcal{L}_{12}v, \mathcal{L}_{21}u + \mathcal{L}_{22}v) = 0 \in\mathcal{W}.
$$
The weak form is given by
$$
\langle y,\mathcal{L} w\rangle = 0,~\forall y\in\mathcal{W}.
$$
We can now proceed using the standard finite element method on our vectorial function space with the induced inner product. The finite element method says that to approximate the solution, we solve the weak form of the equation over a finite-dimensional subspace, which can be accomplished by using our basis functions for test and trial functions. That is, solve the system
$$
\mathbf{L}\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{m+n}, 
$$
where $L_{ij} = \langle\eta_i,\mathcal{L}\eta_j\rangle$. However, we can unroll this back down to the individual components of $w$ in the following way. If we keep the basis ordered like $\{(\varphi_1,0),\dots,(\varphi_m,0),(0,\psi_1),\dots,(0,\psi_n)\}$, then notice the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
i,j\leq m &\implies L_{ij} = \langle\eta_i,\mathcal{L}\eta_j\rangle = \langle (\varphi_i,0),(\mathcal{L}_{11}\varphi_j, \mathcal{L}_{21}\varphi_j)\rangle = (\!(\varphi_i,\mathcal{L}_{11}\varphi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{U}} \\
i\leq m,~m+1\leq j \leq m+n &\implies L_{ij} = \langle\eta_i,\mathcal{L}\eta_j\rangle = \langle (\varphi_i,0),(\mathcal{L}_{12}\psi_j, \mathcal{L}_{22}\psi_j)\rangle = (\!(\varphi_i,\mathcal{L}_{12}\psi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{U}} \\
m+1\leq i \leq m+n,~ j \leq m  &\implies L_{ij} = \langle\eta_i,\mathcal{L}\eta_j\rangle = \langle (0,\psi_i),(\mathcal{L}_{11}\varphi_j, \mathcal{L}_{21}\varphi_j)\rangle = (\!(\psi_i,\mathcal{L}_{21}\varphi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{V}} \\
m+1 \leq i,j \leq m+n  &\implies L_{ij} = \langle\eta_i,\mathcal{L}\eta_j\rangle = \langle (0,\psi_i),(\mathcal{L}_{12}\psi_j, \mathcal{L}_{22}\psi_j)\rangle = (\!(\psi_i,\mathcal{L}_{22}\psi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{V}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Written more succinctly, our finite-element system has a block structure:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{L}_{11} & \mathbf{L}_{12} \\ \mathbf{L}_{21} & \mathbf{L}_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}\\ \mathbf{v}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{0}\\ \mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix},
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left[\mathbf{L}_{11}\right]_{ij}&= (\!(\varphi_i,\mathcal{L}_{11}\varphi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{U}} \\
\left[\mathbf{L}_{12}\right]_{ij}&= (\!(\varphi_i,\mathcal{L}_{12}\psi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{U}} \\
\left[\mathbf{L}_{21}\right]_{ij}&= (\!(\psi_i,\mathcal{L}_{21}\varphi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{V}} \\
\left[\mathbf{L}_{22}\right]_{ij}&= (\!(\psi_i,\mathcal{L}_{11}\psi_j)\!)_{\mathcal{V}}. 
\end{aligned}
$$
This formulation allows for efficient assembly as you can go element-by-element and assemble each component of the blocks.

Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense! What is the practical difference between $((\cdot,\cdot))\mathcal{u}$ and $((\cdot,\cdot))\mathcal{v}$? Are both not simply defined in most cases as $((\phi,\psi))\mathcal{u} = \int_\Omega \phi\psi^* d\Omega$?

Often these are the same, but sometimes the different components of the equations lie in genuinely different function spaces and you need to use the inner products from those spaces. Mixed finite elements deal with this a lot

Can you recommend a good book on Mixed Finite Elements?

Mixed Finite Element Methods and Applications by Boffi, Brezzi, & Fortin

Just to make sure, this same method works if the system is $\mathcal{L}w=f$ and thus the weak form is $\langle y,\mathcal{L} w\rangle = \langle y,f\rangle,~\forall y\in\mathcal{W}$ and thus the linear system becomes $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{f}\in\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$?

Yes. You just need to keep track of which basis elements are tested against the different components of $f$ for the combined system

You mentioned that the function spaces $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ can be different. Am I right in thinking that an example of this would be if $u$ is a vector and $v$ is a scalar and $\mathcal{L}{11}(\cdot)=\nabla\cdot(\cdot)$? In that case how would one handle the case where $(!(\varphi_i,\mathcal{L}{11}\varphi_j)!)_{\mathcal{U}}$ is the inner product of a vector and a scalar? Is the outcome a vector or a scalar?

The output of the operators in the $\mathcal{U}$ equation must lie in the space $\mathcal{U}$, or its dual if you don't have an inner product. Here the divergence is a scalar and you can multiply it by a scalar function and integrate to evaluate the inner product

So $\mathbf{L}_{11} \in (\mathbb{R}^k)^{m\times m}$ is a matrix of vectors that when multiplied with $\mathbf{u} \in (\mathbb{R}^k)^m$ is a vector of vectors, produces $\mathbf{f} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ a vector of scalars? In that case it makes sense, I had never really thought of matrices having non-scalar elements in this way. Thank you.

It is a matrix of scalars. Each scalar is a result of an inner product with basis elements. You will just have a lot more basis elements for a vector-valued function space
